LLM built on top of .md files is returning short answers
I have repo with .md files describing the project. One of the .md files contains description of available executors. There are three executors, lets say A, B, C. When asked "Name all of possible executors" it just gives A. What am I doing wrong, what should I change to get list of all three executors.
reader = SimpleDirectoryReader(input_dir="/Users/xxxx/repos/", required_exts=[".md", ".txt"], recursive=True)
docs = reader.load_data()
        
Settings.llm = OpenAI(model="gpt-3.5-turbo", temperature=0.5, system_prompt="You are an expert on ... and your job is to answer technical questions. Keep your answers technical and based on facts – do not hallucinate features.")
Settings.embed_model = OpenAIEmbedding(model="text-embedding-3-small") # small
Settings.node_parser = SentenceSplitter(chunk_size=512, chunk_overlap=20)
Settings.num_output = 512
Settings.context_window = 3900
        
index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(docs)
chat_engine = index.as_chat_engine(chat_mode="condense_question", verbose=True)

I tried changing model, Settings parameters, but still no luck.

Looks like a common problem. I have similar problem with json data. Tried various setting with no luck.
